# Android: get OnClick for a button from a fragment in the parten FragmentActivity

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have a FragmentActivity which loads a Fragment with several buttons. Now I want to register the onClick-Event of the button in my FragmentActivity.

This is my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Fragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container2, fragment)
            .commit();


        Button button = (Button) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonSettings); 
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                //SettingsActivity activity = new SettingsActivity();
            }       
        }
        );
    }
```

With this code the app crashes when I try to set the OnClickListener in this row:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                //SettingsActivity activity = new SettingsActivity();
            }       
        }
        );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: first, provide logcat stacktrace.

second, check if button is null before you set onclicklistener

Comment: As Tomislav says, the button is probably null because you access it before the fragment has created its view. Why not set the onclicklistener in the fragment, like everybody else does?

Comment: And, btw, why "new SettingsActivity()"? Wouldn't startActivityForResult be easier? or, if you do it in the fragment, getActivity().startActivityForResult...

Comment: This is my first Android project so I have a lot to learn. I have a FragmentActivity that hosts 2 fragments. So I would like to implement all logic directly in the FragmentActivity